# Json.NET serialization of multiple objects that are not in array

Tags: json, serialization, json.net

I have this JSON-like string.

```
{
  "62": {
    "unit_id": "431",
    "staff_id": "444",
    "ext_id": "0",
    "barcode": "1",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "amount": "163.27",
    "status": "Won",
    "won": "43.27",
    "jackpot": "120.00"
  },
  "63": {
    "unit_id": "432",
    "staff_id": "445",
    "ext_id": "0",
    "barcode": "258765424",
    "currency": "EUR",
    "amount": "0.00",
    "status": "Lost",
    "won": "0.00",
    "jackpot": "0.00"
  }
}
```

I want to serialize each of the properties "62", "63" to a model.

Answer (score 0):

I found it. I used JObject.Parse(json) and then I can iterate over the ChildrenTokens property.